# What is the purpose deadline(time.Now()) in golang?

Tags: go

I saw a lot d.deadline(time.Now()) in net package. From the name, I just guess it just set deadline on now, which has no meaning in network communication. So what is the purpose deadline(time.Now()) in golang?

Comment: Can you provide the name of the files you saw it into?

Comment: Do you have a specific piece of code in mind?

Comment: If you were already reading the source, why not look at the actual method definition in the same file? Also, what do you mean by "saw a lot"? That call only appeared once in the source (outside of a test), and has been replaced by `d.deadline(ctx, time.Now())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the function you are referring to (`net` package, file [dial.go](https://golang.org/src/net/dial.go#L191)). So, it returns the first deadline to come between the deadline set and the timeout set for the connection.

```
67  // Return either now+Timeout or Deadline, whichever comes first.
68  // Or zero, if neither is set.
69  func (d *Dialer) deadline(now time.Time) time.Time {
70      if d.Timeout == 0 {
71          return d.Deadline
72      }
73      timeoutDeadline := now.Add(d.Timeout)
74      if d.Deadline.IsZero() || timeoutDeadline.Before(d.Deadline) {
75          return timeoutDeadline
76      } else {
77          return d.Deadline
78      }
79  }
```